# How to define a triangle's side for replacing with the condition on perimeter?

Tags: geometry, proof-writing, triangles

Suppose we have a triangle $\Delta ABC$ and $O$ is an inner point of triangle. It is required to determine which side of the triangle should be replaced on two line segments so that the resulting quadrilateral has a minimum perimeter.

**Statement for Proof:** The minimum distance from  triangle's sides to the inner point will defined the side that should be replaced by two line segments.

[image]

**My attempt.**

Find the distances from the point $O$ to the sides $AB$, $BC$, and $CA$. Let $OD$, $OF$ and $OG$ be the distances. Then take the shortest distance: $\min\{ OD, OF, OG\} = OD$ therefore the side $AB$ should be replaced by on $AO$ and $OB$, because the shortest distance was used the $AOBC$ has a minimum perimeter from possible four-sided polygon $ABOC$, $ABCO$, $AOBC$.

Comment: I'm sorry, but it is hard to figure out what you are saying. You have abbreviated your description of the problem so much it isn't clear what you mean.

Comment: @PaulSinclair, i have tried to improve my description.

Comment: You might like to investigate long, thin triangles where $O$ is closest to the short side, but only very slightly further away from one of the long sides. Can you find a counterexample to your approach?

Comment: @nickgard, one of such example is a triangle with angle greate 90 degrees. In this case distance can't be found (height is out the triangle).